# Regular expression replace, back referencing replaced characters sublime text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a file with the following lines:

```
A 123
B 323
```

Each line starts with either `A` or `B`, and is followed by a blank and a number.

I am trying to convert this into

```
'C [a-z]*A 123'
```

for each line. I use a regex in Find and replace. The regex `[AB] [0-9]*` selects all the lines without a problem. I'm trying to replace it with `'C [a-z]*$1'` that does not print `$1` in the replaced string, and returns:

```
'C [a-z]*'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You missed the capturing group..

Comment: @AvinashRaj What should I change my regex to?

Comment: Why aren't you just inserting what you want at the start of each line?  I'm not seeing the purpose of regex here.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex - `[AB] [0-9]*` - has no round brackets (i.e. no capturing groups that must be present if you wish to reference the captured subtexts later in the relacement string), and thus, you do not get the expected result.

You can use

```
(?m)^[AB][ ]([0-9]{3})
```

Or, if the digits are optional, use `*` quantifier that means *match 0 or more characters as defined with the preceding subpattern*

```
(?m)^[AB][ ]([0-9]*)
```

And replace with

```
'C [a-z]*$1'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lA2aG0/1)

Comment: what if the number doesn't have to have 3 digits?

Comment: Use a `*` quantifier that will make the digits presence optional. What is of interest is that even if there are no digits, the empty string will still be captured and referenced to by `$1`. Once set, the capturing group is always there in Group 1.